# how to create a stored procedure that takes the start and end dates of the sales between the start and the end dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is my first time using this, apologies for any confusion.

I am trying to create a stored procedure that takes the start and end dates of the sales and display all the sales transactions between the start and the end dates in  MYSQL.

So I have 2 tables:

1. orders which contains the orders dates (order_date)
2. transactions with all transactions of each order
   both linked by order_ID

This is my code

```
DELIMITER //

 CREATE PROCEDURE gettransactions(IN `start date` date , `end date` date)

BEGIN
 
SELECT * FROM  transactions t

join orders o on t.order_id = o.order_id

WHERE (o.order_date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(o.order_date)) FROM orders) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(o.order_date)) FROM orders));

  
END //
```

The code runs fine and I get this to insert the tables (sorry I dont know why I am unable to add the screentshot directly here):
https://i.ibb.co/fMdPF48/sql.png

My problem is, regardless the dates I insert, the outcome is always all the transactions I have in the table. So let's say I want all the transactions from the 7th of April until the 25th of June, I should use:

```
call chicgirls.gettransactions('2020-04-07', '2020-06-25');
```

The outcome should be the transactions of the orders in this range, why am I getting all the transactions? It happens regardless the dates I inster.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your procedure never uses the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the parameters in your query. You're selecting all orders, since you're selecting everything between the min and max dates in the same table.

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions AS t
JOIN orders AS o ON t.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN `start date` AND `end date`;
```

Comment: so simple, and very precise.. I was stuck on this because I thought for the clause "where X between Y and Z" Y and Z must be a value or a column/field name. Thank you so much!

Comment: Variables can be used anywhere that values can be used.